# Speed voltage variation in alternators

Tags: synchronous, alternator, synchronous-motor

What happens to the terminal voltage of synchronous generator  if we change the speed  ?

Comment: Have you tried to search for the answer in something like a search engine?

Comment: @Abhijith A good question will generate good answers, it looks like you took about 3 seconds to write this question and its not specific enough. Take some time and write a good specific question (maybe what you think about the problem and why) and you'll get good answers

Answer (score 0):

For every kind of electromagnetic generator, the voltage produced is directly proportional to the speed of the relevant motion multiplied by the relevant magnetic flux.